# How do I fix this div?

Tags: html, css, wrapper

I am trying to fix the little spacing between my images to form one whole image in a sense. Here is a picture: http://gyazo.com/ecaf4c33f97c6ad4de9d4276809daea6 - I'm talking about the light blue line below the orange line on the nav bar.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #5c6376;  
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 12em; 
    padding: 0px;
}

#topMenu {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#body1 {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position:relative;
}

#text {
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    right: 735px;
}

#body2 {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#body3 {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div align = "center">
        <img src="img/top-bar.png" width="1017" height="87" alt="" id="topMenu">    
    </div>
    <div align = "center">
        <h2 id="text">Test</h2>
        <img src="img/body1.png" width="1017" height="445" alt="" id="body1">
    </div>
    <div align = "center">
        <img src="img/body2.png" width="1017" height="445" alt="" id="body2">
    </div>
    <div align = "center">
        <img src="img/body3.png" width="1017" height="366" alt="" id="body2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you'll get more help if you discuss what you've tried, as well as include a link to your issue in a live form, via something like http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you try using

```
#body1 {
min-height: 100%;
min-width: auto;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
position:relative;
top:-10px;
left: 0;
}
```

if top :-10px does not work, experiment with the value till the gap vanishes

Comment: i use it all the time with position:relative and it works fine

Comment: Thanks, I've sorted it now.